# How to create a continuous legend (color bar style) for scale_alpha?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Currently, a [continuous colour bar legend, `guide_colorbar`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_colourbar.html) is available only with `scale_fill` and `scale_colour`, and not with `scale_alpha`. The legend which is generated with  `scale_alpha` is of a discrete type ([`guide_legend`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html)).

A small example where `color` and `alpha` are mapped to a continuous variable:

`scale_color` generates a continuous color bar type legend :

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

`scale_alpha` generates a discrete legend, despite `alpha` is mapped to a continuous variable:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, alpha = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Is there some way to get a continuous color bar legend also for `scale_alpha`?

Comment: `scale_alpha` may be what you're looking for

Comment: scale_alpha (or scale_alpha_continous) will indeed plot alpha values on a continuous scale, but the legend is on a discrete scale. I'm looking for a way to make the legend reflect the fact that the plotted values are continuous and not discrete.

Comment: So you're plotting continuous data with it, but the legend shows the breaks as separate values, whereas you want it to have the appearance of a colourbar, as with `scale_colour_continuous`? Is that right?

Comment: @Brian - correct.

Comment: This is a surprisingly tricky one. I'm working on an answer, but it's apparently coded in as not an intended use case: `Error in guides_train(scales = scales, theme = theme, guides = guides,  : 
  Guide 'colorbar' cannot be used for 'alpha'.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default minimum alpha for `scale_alpha_continuous` is 0.1, and the max is 1. I wrote this assuming that you might adjust the minimum to be more visible, but you'd keep the max at 1.

First I set `amin` to that default of 0.1, and the chosen colour for the points as `highcol`. Then we use the `col2rgb` to make a matrix of the RGB values and blend them with white, as modified from [this answer written in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195764/3330437). Note that we're blending with white, so you should be using a theme that has a white background (e.g. `theme_classic()` as below). Finally we convert that matrix to hex values and paste it into a single string with `#` in front for standard RGB format.

```
require(scales)
amin <- 0.1

highcol <- hue_pal()(1)       # or a color name like "blue"

lowcol.hex <- as.hexmode(round(col2rgb(highcol) * amin + 255 * (1 - amin)))
lowcol <- paste0("#",   sep = "",
                 paste(format(lowcol.hex, width = 2), collapse = ""))
```

Then we plot as you might be planning to already, with your variable of choice set to the `alpha` aesthetic, and here some `geom_point`s. Then we plot another layer of points, but with **colour** set to that same variable, and `alpha = 0` (or invisible). This gives us our colourbar we need. Then we have to set the range of `scale_colour_gradient` to our colours from above.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, alpha = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(colour = highcol, size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Petal.Length), alpha = 0) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(high = highcol, low = lowcol) + 
  guides(alpha = F) + 
  labs(colour = "Alpha\nlabel") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

I'm guessing you most often would want to use this with only a single colour, and for that colour to be black. In that simplified case, replace `highcol` and `lowcol` with "black" and "grey90". If you want to have multiple colours, each with an alpha varied by some other variable... that's a whole other can of worms and probably not a good idea.

---

### Edited to add in a bad idea!

If you replace colour with fill for my solution above, you can still use colour as an aesthetic. Here I used `highcol <-hue_pal()(3)[2]` to extract that default green colour.

```
ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, alpha = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species), size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Length), alpha = 0) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(high = highcol, low = lowcol) + 
  guides(alpha = F) + 
  labs(fill = "Petal\nLength") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]