# tweaks to customized legends with ggplot and cowplot: colour matching issue

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to create a picture with points (actually bars, but whatever) in two distinct colours with parallel saturated-to-unsaturated colour scales, with corresponding colourbar legends. I'm most of the way there, but there are a few minor points I can't handle yet.

**tl;dr** the color scales I get from a red-to-white gradient and a saturated-red-to-completely-unsaturated gradient are not identical.

Set up data: `y` will determine both y-axis position and degree of saturation, `w` will determine binary colour choice.

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100))
dd$w <- as.logical(sample(0:1,size=nrow(dd),
                          replace=TRUE))
```

Get packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(gridExtra)
```

I can get the plot I want by allowing alpha (transparency) to vary with `y`, but the legend is ugly:

```
g0 <- ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+
   geom_point(size=8,aes(alpha=y,colour=w))+
   scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
   ## +     scale_alpha(guide="colourbar")  ## doesn't work
```

I can draw each half of the points by themselves to get a legend similar to what I want:

```
g1 <- ggplot(dd[!dd$w,],aes(x,y))+
    geom_point(size=8,aes(colour=y))+
    scale_colour_gradient(low="white",high="red",name="not w")+
    expand_limits(x=range(dd$x),y=range(dd$y))

g2 <- ggplot(dd[dd$w,],aes(x,y))+
   geom_point(size=8,aes(colour=y))+
   scale_colour_gradient(low="white",high="blue",name="w")+
   expand_limits(x=range(dd$x),y=range(dd$y))
```

[image]

Now I can use tools from `cowplot` to pick off the legends and combine them with the original plot:

```
g1_leg <- get_legend(g1)
g2_leg <- get_legend(g2)
g0_noleg <- g0 + theme(legend.position='none')
ggdraw(plot_grid(g0_noleg,g1_leg,g2_leg,nrow=1,rel_widths=c(1,0.2,0.2)))
```

[image]

This is most of the way there, but:

- ideally I'd like to squash the two colourbars together (I know I can probably do that with sufficient grid-hacking ...)
- the colours don't quite match; the legend colours are slightly warmer than the point colours ...

Ideas?  Or other ways of achieving the same goal?

Comment: To fix the color/legend matching, you can use an old hack by koshke to overlap `g1` and `g2`, which is [here](https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2). (Just ignore all the axis stuff.) Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Also, if they are bars, does that mean that they are no negative y-values? Because then you could potentially define a two way gradient .

Comment: I tried out some ideas on this recently. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171042/3330437