# Combining 2 RGB Colors With Alpha

Tags: java, colors, rgb, bufferedimage, rgba

I'm trying (In Java) to get the resulting color when I combine 2 colors, the one on top having an alpha transparency. Basically, I'm trying to assign a background color to an image, but I've broken it down to each pixel being changed individually. I've looked at several articles, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506117/calculate-resulting-rgb-from-2-colors-one-is-transparent), to no avail. Does anybody know how to perform this kind of RGBA/RGB color mixing? My current code uses this png:

[image: PNG Image]

And produces this JPG:

[image: JPG Image]

This is the function that I'm currently using. The background for the demo images was set to full blue, or an int of 255.

```
public static void PNGToJPEGConvert(String PNGPath, String NewJPEGPath, int BackColor) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(PNGPath));
        BufferedImage newImage;
        int R1, G1, B1, R2 = (BackColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16, G2 = (BackColor & 0xFF00) >> 8, B2 = (BackColor & 0xFF), W1, W2, W3, M1, M2, R3, G3, B3;
        float br;
        newImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        for(int x=0; x < bufferedImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y=0; y < bufferedImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                R1 = BufferedImageGetPixelARGB(bufferedImage, "R", x, y);
                G1 = BufferedImageGetPixelARGB(bufferedImage, "G", x, y);
                B1 = BufferedImageGetPixelARGB(bufferedImage, "B", x, y);
                W1 = Math.min(R1, Math.min(G1, B1));
                W2 = Math.min(R2, Math.min(G2, B2));
                R1 -= W1;
                G1 -= W1;
                B1 -= W1;
                R2 -= W2;
                G2 -= W2;
                M1 = Math.max(R1, Math.max(G1, B1));
                M2 = Math.max(R2, Math.max(G2, B2));
                br = (M1 + M2)/(2*BufferedImageGetPixelARGB(bufferedImage, "A", x, y));
                R3 = (int) ((R1 + R2) * br);
                G3 = (int) ((G1 + G2) * br);
                B3 = (int) ((B1 + B2) * br);
                W3 = (W1 + W2) / 2;
                R3 += W3;
                G3 += W3;
                B3 += W3;
                newImage.setRGB(x, y, RGBValuesToInt(R3, G3, B3));
            }
        }
        try {
            ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", new File(NewJPEGPath));
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help,
-Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is

```
float masking_factor = mask_value/255.0;
composed_value = int(
    source_pixel_value * (1 - masking_factor) + 
    overlay_pixel_value * masking_factor
);
```

We suppose that all values are 8-bit, that is, 0 to 255, and `mask` is monochrome. Where `mask` is completely black, it is fully transparent, and only source pixels are visible. Where `mask` is completely white, it is fully opaque, and only overlay pixels are visible. Values in between give intermediate opacity.

But if alpha blending is the *only* thing you want to implement, there are better ways to do it than working with individual pixels. See [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and its `.setComposite()` method.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static Color mixColorsWithAlpha(Color color1, Color color2, int alpha)
{
    float factor = alpha / 255f;
    int red = (int) (color1.getRed() * (1 - factor) + color2.getRed() * factor);
    int green = (int) (color1.getGreen() * (1 - factor) + color2.getGreen() * factor);
    int blue = (int) (color1.getBlue() * (1 - factor) + color2.getBlue() * factor);
    return new Color(red, green, blue);
}
```

This would be the same as painting color2 (with the given alpha value) over color1.

Comment: This helped me mix a colour with black to get a darker version of itself. Thanks!